# Replace paragraph tag using regex

Tags: php, regex

I need to take the output of `$one` and make an array, however, the regex is not right because all I get back is an array with one key and one value; basically, the entire string. If there are 10 paragraph tags in the string then I should get 10 values in the array.

What is wrong with my regex?

Ideally, what I would like to have in the output array are two arrays, one with the paragraph tags and another with just the text between them.

```
$one = preg_replace( '/<p>/i', '<p class="test">', $str ); // This gives me what I need
print_r(explode( '/<p class="test">/iU', $one )); // This does not
```

Comment: I know i shouldn't but... http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/496223

Comment: @yes123, thanks for the link. I thought regex could parse anything.. Would you have a suggestion how I get the output of $one into an array?

Comment: afaik, `explode` cannot split according to a regex, but `preg_split` might help.

Comment: Yea, I did palm face too when I discovered regex can't do everything

Comment: note that because of the nested nature of html, regexps might not be the best way to handle it

Comment: maybe you need an [html parser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/292926/robust-mature-html-parser-for-php) compatible with xpath queries.

Comment: Just to clarify, there will be no nested html to parse. I am only ever going to throw paragraph tags at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is simple.  Explode does not use regex.  This should work for you.

```
print_r(explode('<p class="test">', $one ));
```

EDIT: This ought to do what you want.

```
$pattern = '/(?P<open><p class="test">)'
          . '(?P<content>.*)'
          . '(?P<close><\/p>)/i';
preg_match_all($pattern, $one, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

EDIT: Simplified version without the match tags:

```
$pattern = '/(<p class="test">)(.*)(<\/p>)/i';
preg_match_all($pattern, $one, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Comment: thanks. This does in fact work but I was hoping to get the paragraph tags in the array. I don't think that explode will do this. Is there another alternative?

Comment: preg_match will allow you to match elements... gimme a minute.

Comment: I've tried this but get 14 empty arrays. `print_r(preg_split( '/<p class="test">(.*)<\/p>/iU', $one ));`

Comment: Thanks. This is what I get: `preg_match(): Unknown modifier 'p'`

Comment: Fixed that bug... missing escape on the /

Comment: BTW, you don't need the <open>, <close>, and <content> tags - those allow you to have associative references for the output.  We could remove those, and you could access the same data by index (0, 1, and 2) if you prefer.

Comment: Thanks. OK, it's getting a little better. I've now got 3 of the 14 values. It only matched 3.

Comment: Now you're cookin'!  Thank you my friend!

Comment: This could be just `'#<p class="test">(.*?)</p>#i'`, much easier to read imho.

Comment: Jack, true, but he wanted the `<p>` and `</p>` in their own arrays, no?

Comment: Either way is just fine. It's working just great and gives me exactly what I need. :)

Comment: Maybe try `#<p class="test">(.*?)<\/p>#i` to see if it suits your needs?

Comment: @TheSmose, I got it to work **after** I changed the css class to match what was returned from `$one`. Sheesh.. :)

Comment: Maybe this isn't the right place for this, but I have to ask... What are the hash tags doing in Jack's code?

Comment: Yes, it will only match the `<p>` with the `class` attribute added.  You can strip that out of the regex, though.

Comment: @TheSmose. When I strip out the hashes, I get `preg_match_all(): Unknown modifier '(' `. Any idea why?

Comment: The hashes (`#`) or slashes (`/`) are necessary at the beginning and end.  They the regex delimiters.  Without them, you don't have a valid regex.